# Move HTML object with JavaScript while key is pressed

Tags: javascript, html, vue.js, frontend

I'm writing a little game with vueJS as the frontend. I managed to create all the needed objects and now I want to make them move if a key is pressed.

My problem is I can only move them once when the key is pressed. I want to move it consistently while the key is pressed.

My Code for moving is:

```js
let myCircle = document.querySelector('.ball');
var key_left = false;

window.addEventListener('load', () =>{
    myCircle.style.position = 'absolute';
    myCircle.style.left = 0 + 'px';
    myCircle.style.top = 1200 + 'px';
});

window.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {

if (event.key == 'ArrowLeft')
    key_left = true;

if (key_left == true)
{
    myCircle.style.left = parseInt(myCircle.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
}
```

When I tried to add a while loop it stopped moving at all.

Code:

```js
let myCircle = document.querySelector('.ball');
var key_left = false;

window.addEventListener('load', () =>{
    myCircle.style.position = 'absolute';
    myCircle.style.left = 0 + 'px';
    myCircle.style.top = 1200 + 'px';
});

window.addEventListener('keyup', (event) => {

if (event.key == 'ArrowLeft')
    key_left = true;

while (key_left == true)
{
    myCircle.style.left = parseInt(myCircle.style.left) - 5 + 'px';
}
});
```

Does someone have a hint for me?

Thanks!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Try to use the `keydown` event instead, it is fired every tick.

Or check out the examples at w3school.
https://www.w3schools.com/jsref/event_onkeydown.asp

```js
window.addEventListener('keydown', (event) => {
    myCircle.style.left = parseInt(myCircle.style.left) - 5 + 'px'
}
```

Comment: Thank you! It works like this :)